# C# XML Reader returning none when trying to access XML file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlreader

I am deserializing following xml which is generated by serialization.

```
<BattInfo>
  <Battery>
    <BattName>TestBattery</BattName>
    <NumCellSeries>12</NumCellSeries>
    <NumCellParallel>10</NumCellParallel>
    <CelltoPackResistanceSum>3</CelltoPackResistanceSum>
    <BattThermalResistance>15</BattThermalResistance>
    <BattHeatCapacity>12</BattHeatCapacity>
  </Battery>
</BattInfo>
```

Code I am using is:

```
public class BattModel
{
    public string BattName { get; set; }
    public double NumCellSeries { get; set; }
    public double NumCellParallel { get; set; }
    public double CelltoPackResistanceSum { get; set; }
    public double BattThermalResistance { get; set; }
    public double BattHeatCapacity { get; set; }

}

public class BattInfo
{
    [XmlElement("Battery")]
    public List<BattModel> Battery { get; set; }

    public BattInfo()
    {
        this.Battery = new List<BattModel>();
    }
    public BattInfo(params BattModel[] data) : this()
    {
        this.Battery.AddRange(data);
    }
    public void Save(string filename)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filename, settings);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BattInfo));
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, this,ns);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }
    public BattInfo Load(string filename)
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filename);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BattInfo));
        return (BattInfo)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }


}
```

The xml gets serialized properly. But when I try to read it from the xml that is generated using serialization, it returns none while reading the file through xmlreader.

Comment: The code work with this call :            BattInfo loadedData = batteryInfo.Load(FILENAME);  You are returning the serialized data and may be you want this = (BattInfo)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

Comment: @jdweng The thing is that when I am using breakpoint, I find that reader is not getting populated in this Load function. Value for reader is {None}.

Comment: @jdweng - `this = (BattInfo)serializer.Deserialize(reader);` is not right... If you try you should get: *Cannot assign to '<this>' because it is read-only*

Comment: That is what I also get.  If must be making a copy of the reader.  The reader shows none until it is advanced from the start.  The Deserialize() method returns data.

Comment: Right, you  cannot use this.

Comment: Making function static and using  BattInfo loadedData = BattInfo.Load(FILENAME); worked. I cleared many concepts about classes after that. I am glad you people helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the `Load` method static and tried this... It works fine here. Here is the code:

```
void Main()
{
    new BattInfo(new BattModel(){ BattName= "test"}).Save(@"tmp.xml");  
    Console.Out.Write(BattInfo.Load(@"tmp.xml").Battery[0].BattName);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class BattModel
{
    public string BattName { get; set; } 
    public double NumCellSeries { get; set; }
    public double NumCellParallel { get; set; }
    public double CelltoPackResistanceSum { get; set; }
    public double BattThermalResistance { get; set; }
    public double BattHeatCapacity { get; set; }

}

public class BattInfo
{
    [XmlElement("Battery")]
    public List<BattModel> Battery { get; set; }

    public BattInfo()
    {
        this.Battery = new List<BattModel>();
    }
    public BattInfo(params BattModel[] data) : this()
    {
        this.Battery.AddRange(data);
    }
    public void Save(string filename)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filename, settings);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BattInfo));
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, this,ns);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }
    public static BattInfo Load(string filename)
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filename);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BattInfo));
        return (BattInfo)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Were you expecting the `Load` method to populate the existing instance you called it from? In short, `XmlSerializer` is strictly constructive so you can't by design.

Comment: Yes, I want to populate instance.

Comment: Why do you want to populate an existing instance? Surely `BattInfo.Load(s)` makes more sense than `new BattInfo().Load(s)`...

Comment: Okay. I have used this, BattInfo battInfo = BattInfo.Load(filepath); But issue is not there, issue is I am getting none when I read the file.

Comment: Yes it is working when I make this static. Can you explain why it worked? I am new to coding. I am embarrassed to ask such questions. But I am not clear why it worked.

Comment: erm... Not sure... With your original code `new BattInfo().Load(s)` was working too... It was just returning a new instance and not populating the existing one.